# How to reduce this code and is it possible to skip this call failing fast?

Tags: rust

#### First question

Is there a way to reduce this code?

```rust
struct FileInput {
  pub list: Option<Vec<String>>
}

async fn file_create(
  input: &FileInput,
) -> Result<()> {
  if let Some(list) = input.list {
    if !list.is_empty() {
      handle().await?;
        }
    };

    // Other methods to execute here whether input.list is empty or not

    Ok(())
}
```

#### Second question

And how to fail fast skipping this call if the list is empty?

I do not understand if it's possible to do this:

```rust
async fn file_create(
    input: &FileInput,
) -> Result<()> {
    if let Some(list) = input.list {
        if list.is_empty() {
          // how to exit here?
        }

        handle().await?;
    };

    // Other methods to execute here whether input.list is empty or not

    Ok(())
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way is to instead include the code to execute if the list is not empty under `if !list.is_empty()`:

```rust
async fn file_create(
    input: &FileInput,
) -> Result<()> {
    if let Some(list) = input.list {
        if !list.is_empty() {
            handle().await?;
        }
    };

    // Other methods to execute here whether input.list is empty or not

    Ok(())
}
```

But if you want, you can use the fact that you can `break` out of a block:

```rust
async fn file_create(
    input: &FileInput,
) -> Result<()> {
    'check_list: {
        if let Some(list) = input.list {
            if list.is_empty() {
                break 'check_list;
            }

            handle().await?;
        }
    };

    // Other methods to execute here whether input.list is empty or not

    Ok(())
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Is there a way to reduce `if let Some(list) = input.list {
        if !list.is_empty() {`?

Comment: On nightly using `#![feature(let_chains)]`: `if let Some(list) = input.list && !list.is_empty()`. On stable, assuming `list` is a slice: `if let Some(list @ [_, ..]) = input.list`.

Comment: or `!input.list.map(Vec::is_empty).unwrap_or(true)`

Comment: @Holloway This doesn't bind `list`, so not exactly the same. Also, `unwrap_or(false)`.

Comment: True, but `list` wasn't used in the `handle().await?` block so I didn't think it was needed. I think it needs to be `unwrap_or(true)`. If `input.list` is `None`, the block shouldn't be entered.

Comment: @Holloway Oh, you negate it. Yes.